# RN 0.63 How to resume music played in background by other app, after my app finishes playing own file

Tags: react-native, audio, spotify, onresume, background-music

One of the functionality of my_app (React Native 0.63) is to "read some content" when on given screen. On focus there is a 'someTextToSpeech.mp3' file launched.
Expect behaviour is: when user has any music on, played from other app in the background (f.e. Spotify), when 'someTextToSpeech.mp3' is launched, the music should be stoped, and resume after the 'someTextToSpeech.mp3' is over.
I am using react-native-audio-toolkit to play 'someTextToSpeech.mp3' with config "mixWithOthers" set to false. The background music (in my case Spotify) stops after the 'someTextToSpeech.mp3' is launched but doesn't resume after someTextToSpeech.mp3 if finished.
Do you know a way how to resume music previously played on device by other app, after the media from my_app is over?

Thank you for your time and hope for some help.
K

Comment: Hello, iam facing same issue using react-native-sound library.. u found a solution for this issue?

Comment: any solution for that issue?